# Meu while encerra antes do que realmente deveria

Tags: python, while, for

Eu fiz um código que deveria pegar o número de linhas de um arquivo txt e depois, utilizar este mesmo número de linhas em um while para converter as colunas e linhas em array.

```
lines = 0
ln = 0

for line in dataset:
    line = line.strip()
    lines += 1
    print (lines, ln)

while ln < (lines):
    line1 = dataset.readline()
    if not line1: break
    words = str.split(line1)
    ln += 1
```

No caso em que estou trabalhando, o arquivo tem 551 linhas, mas o código sempre se encerra quando o ln chega aos 275

Comment: Já viu o que tem na linha 275? pode ser que o conteúdo esteja tornando verdadeira a expressão `if not line1: break` tente usar `for ln in range(lines)` ao invés do `while`

Answer (score 0):

Você está usando o mesmo dataset aberto no while, sendo que ele já foi consumido até o EOF no for, chegando no fim do arquivo, se você der dataset.close() e der open no dataset novamente antes do while, o seu laço não entrará no break.

Answer (score 0):

Coloque um

> print ln

no fibal do loop while para verificar se ele realmente não está fazendo todas as iterações ou se ele tá entrando nesse seu if not e não tá gerando o resultado que você espera.